# program doesn't work probably 'cause segmentation fault

Tags: c

Please tell me why my program isn't working. I think it may be a segmentation fault but I can't identify it. If possible please correct it.

I'm trying to convert from array of char to an array of int using function chartoint() and when I remove it from main it works so the problem is in the function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void chartoint(char c[],int * x){
    int i;
    while(c[i]!='.'||c[i]!='\0'){
        if((int)c[i]>57){ *(x+i) = (int)c[i] - 54;}
        else{ *(x+i) = (c[i]-'0'); }
        i++;
    }
    *(x+i) = -1; i++;
    while(c[i]!='\0'){
        if((int)c[i]>57){ *(x+i) = (int)c[i] - 54;}
        else{ *(x+i) = (c[i]-'0'); }
        i++;
    }
}

int main(){
    int n;
    printf(" number of characters ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char c[n+1];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%c",&c[i]);
    }
    c[n]='\0';
    int * x = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    chartoint(c,x);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%d",*(x+i));
    }
    free(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Local variables (like your variable `i` in the `chartoint` function) are *uninitialized* by default. They will have an *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) value. Always remember to initialize local variables before you use them.

Comment: Also please don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), as they make the code harder to read and understand. If by `54` you mean the [ASCII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) character `'6'` then say so. But why `'6'`? What is that check for really about? It makes no sense.

Comment: Lastly, you should know that for *any* pointer or array `x` and index `i`, the expression `*(x + i)` is *exactly* equal to `x[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn how to use a debugger.

Here's the output when you use a debugger to run your C program (gdb, in this case). I named your compiled program `t`:

```
$ gdb ./t
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.3) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./t...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/youruser/t 
 number of characters 3
a

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004006ba in chartoint (c=0x7fffffffe540 "\na\n", x=0x602010) at t.c:6
6       while(c[i]!='.'||c[i]!='\0'){
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004006ba in chartoint (c=0x7fffffffe540 "\na\n", x=0x602010) at t.c:6
#1  0x0000000000400884 in main () at t.c:29
(gdb)
```

It's basically saying that you are getting a segmentation fault (`SIGSEGV`) when running line 6. The reason is probably that `i` it's being used without being initialized first.

If you are using an IDE to do this (Visual Studio, Visual Studio Code) you will probably have and embedded debugger.